# Como alternar entre as câmeras (Front, Back)?

Tags: android, android-camera

Estou fazendo uma aplicação Android nativa, usando as câmeras do dispositivo. Depois que eu inicio a primeira Activity, chamando a câmera (Back), criei um botão, com a função de alternar entre as câmeras (Front, Back).

Só que estou com um pouco de dificuldade em fazer tal função. Que pegue a câmera que está sendo utilizada e mude para outra, tipo (Front --> Back/ Back --> Front). Poderiam me ajudar a resolver esse problema?

Código abaixo -->

```
public void cameraFrontal(View view){
        int numCamera = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        if(numCamera < 0){
            Log.i("Script", "Nenhuma câmera encontrada");
        }else {
            if(cameraManager.isOpen() == true && numCamera == 2){
                Log.i("Script", "Camera --> " + cameraInfo.facing);
                if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Chamada da Câmera Frontal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Chamada da Câmera Traseira", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: O que é que já tentaste fazer?

Comment: Apenas, estou verificando se existe câmeras no dispositivo,
Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
  if(numCamera < 0){

Comment: depois disso, era verificar qual câmera está sendo executada (Frontal ou Traseira).
Feito isso, colocar função de alternar entre elas, usando um Botão, por exemplo.

Comment: Você pode [edit] a pergunta colocando o código relevante.

Comment: Na verdade, queria fazer com o que toda vez que eu clicasse no botão, o método identificasse qual câmera está sendo executada (se é a frontal ou a traseira) e depois trocasse de câmera, se estivesse usando a câmera traseira iria trocar pela frontal e assim vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Espero que isso t ajude:

Escolhendo a câmera

Um dispositivo pode ter várias câmeras, uma câmera ou nenhuma. Para identificar o número exato é possível fazer a seguinte chamada (disponível a partir do Android 2.3):

```
int qtde = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
```

O primeiro passo para trabalhar com uma câmera é obter uma instância de um objeto Camera (classe presente no pacote android.hardware.Camera). Isto pode ser feito desta forma:

```
 Camera camera = Camera.open();
```

Esta chamada retorna a referência à câmera traseira do dispositivo (retorna null caso ela não exista). Para referenciar outras câmeras, é preciso utilizar o método open() sobrecarregado, que recebe um int como parâmetro. Este parâmetro indica qual o ID da câmera, que pode variar de 0 até o número de câmeras subtraído de 1.

Um detalhe importante com relação à câmera é que ela deve ser liberada após o uso. Isto é feito através da seguinte chamada:

```
 camera.release();
```

Além disso, quando você acessa diretamente a câmera, o Android solicita que você declare uma permissão específica na sua aplicação, como pode ser visto abaixo:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Essa explicação foi retirada do site: http://www.softblue.com.br/blog/home/postid/15/UTILIZANDO_CAMERAS_EM_APLICACOES_ANDROID